# Is the cost of $\lVert \mathbf{v} \rVert_2$ really $O(n)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, computational-complexity

What is the complexity (in flops, floating-point operations) of taking the $l_2$-norm of vector $\mathbf{v}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ (or $\mathbf{v}\in\mathbb{C}^n$ if a difference exists).

We have the following definition of the $l_2$-norm of $\mathbf{v}$:

$$
\lVert\mathbf{v}\rVert_2= \sqrt{|v_1|^2+\dots+|v_n|^2}
$$

where $|v_i|$ is the absolute value of $v_i$ (or complex modulus if $v_i$ complex).

I fount that the square-root is usually considered as one flop which makes this operation cost $2n$ flops ($n$ multiplications (for squares), $n-1$ additions and one square-root).

Is it correct to consider the square-root operation as a flop?

Comment: Whether it does or doesn't, it'll be implemented as a constant number of flops that doesn't change with $n$.

Comment: The rule of thumb is that a square root takes time equivalent to about 100 flops.  But it is a constant, so can be ignored for large $ n $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule of thumb is that a square root takes time equivalent to about 100 flops. But it is a constant, so can be ignored for large $n$.

In practice, the two norm is not computed this way.  The reason is that the squaring of a large element (or a small one) can cause unnecessary overflow or underflow.  What is done instead is that the largest entry (in magnitude) is determined (let's say $ v_{\rm max} $ and then each element is divided by that:
$ v = \frac{1}{v_{\rm max}} $.  Then $ \| v \|_2 = v_{\rm max} \| \frac{1}{v_{\rm max}} v \|_2 $.  This increases the cost, but in the end still requires $ O(n) $ time.

Comment: A relevant point but I think that your comments answers better the question. Would do be willing to include your comment to the answer so that I can mark it as correct, thanks.

Comment: I have done what you requested!